Not Understanding the Proof
On the paper A Proof of a Conjecture of Ohba by Noel, Reed, and Wu, I cannot understand the following proof and the logic behind it.

How can we construct proper surjective colouring $g$ from given proper colouring $f$ such that satisfies either $a$ or $b$?
Actually, I don't know how the result follows.
Thank for your time.
edit: I just added corollary $1.8$ and its origin.


It would be easier to understand the proof, if you could provide Corollary 1.8 in your question, which this proof seems to use.

@Immi: I added.

It helps to understand all of this backwards: to explain the proof, and then figure out what the proof accomplishes.
Consider the following procedure on a vertex coloring:

Pick a color $c$ that is currently not used at all.
Change the color of vertex $h(c)$ to $c$.
Repeat steps 1-2 for as long as there are unused colors to pick.

It is not immediately obvious that the procedure even terminates, because along the way, we might get new unused colors (having recolored all the vertices where they were previously used). To prove that it does terminate, note that every color $c$ is picked at most once! Once we have changed the color of vertex $h(c)$ to $c$, the procedure will never apply any other color to $h(c)$ (because $h$ is injective), so vertex $h(c)$ will always stay color $c$, so $c$ will never again become an unused color.
If we start with a proper coloring $f\colon V(G) \to C$, and end with a coloring $g\colon V(G) \to C$, then Proposition 1.13 is merely summarizing the properties of the resulting coloring $g$, relative to $f$.
First, $g$ is still proper. The recoloring procedure never creates two adjacent vertices of the same color, because it only applies color $c$ to a vertex if that color is not used anywhere else in the graph!
Second, $g$ is surjective. This is the only way that the recoloring procedure can terminate.
Third, the recoloring procedure is an improvement on how often the coloring "cheats" by giving a vertex a color not on its vertex list. Conditions (a)-(b) are just an attempt to quantify that. So let's try to quantify it:
Suppose that for a vertex $v \in V(G)$, condition (a) does not hold, and $g(v) \notin L(v)$. Then the recoloring procedure has never recolored $v$, because whenever the recoloring procedure applies color $c$ to a vertex $h(c)$, we always have $c \in L(h(c))$. Therefore color $g(v)$ has never been picked (because it has always remained present on $g(v)$). Therefore:

$g(v) = f(v)$: the color of $v$ is the same as it was originally.
$g^{-1}(g(v))$ (the set of vertices using this color now) is a subset of $f^{-1}(f(v))$ (the set of vertices using this color originally). That's because color $g(v)$ has never been picked, so the only changes to the set of vertices using it have been from some of them getting recolored to something else.

But all this just says that condition (b) holds at $v$. So what we've shown is exactly the statement of Proposition 1.13!
(The proof of Proposition 1.13 is very different because it's the non-algorithmic version of the argument above. If you want to prove something about the result of an iterative algorithm without ever mentioning that algorithm, then you must do what this proof does: use the extremal principle to "skip to the end" of the algorithm by choosing the coloring $g$ where our recoloring procedure has been done as many times as possible. In this case, I think it's not worth it, because it's less clear.)
